# idToken generated from react-native-google-signin does not work with google fit API returns status code 401 wrong auth credentials on request

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-oauth, google-fit

I am working on a PWA which is wrapped in a react native container, I use  `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("data to send")` to pass data back and forth to the PWA and react native app.

I am trying to integrate google fit API, in order to access the API an access token is needed, so I use the `react-native-google-signin` package to provide auth details to my app but when I store the `idToken` and send it to PWA, and make a request for fetching the steps it is returning me error 401, wrong auth credentials.

The whole flow is working fine when I only integrate it in the PWA and get the auth details via `react-google-login` and run my app in the browser, here I am also able to get the steps count via google fit API hence everything works fine but when trying it on a mobile device it does redirect me to the google login page but does not get back to my app, which in return gives me the error that user closed the app or user denied google auth, so I had to get the token from the react native app itself and pass it to PWA then making request using that API token but it does not work either.

Has anyone been through this situation ?

Other details I have generated `WEB_CLIENT_ID` for the web app, and also added the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint for the android app.

**In the react native app,**

```
  const signInGoogleAuth = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log('user after google auth', user);
      // await webViewRef.postMessage(user);
      sendDataToPWA(JSON.stringify(user));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Some other error, please try again!', error);
    }
  };
```

**PWA App**

Here I am storing the `user` object in the redux store hence obtained with the auth token inside the user object.

Further making a request to fetch to google fit API to fetch steps,

```
export const getRequestHeaders = accessToken => {
  const requestHeaderBody = {
    params: {
      key: API_KEY, // generated from google API console
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // stored API token from react native
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  };
  return requestHeaderBody;
};
```

```
export const getAggregatedDataBody = (dataType, endTime) => {
  const requestBody = {
    aggregateBy: [
      {
        dataTypeName: dataType,
      },
    ],
    bucketByTime: {
      durationMillis: 86400000,
    },
    endTimeMillis: endTime,
    startTimeMillis: endTime - 7 * 86400000,
  };
  return requestBody;
};

export const getAggregateData = async (body, headers) => {
  const req = await axios.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate',
    body,
    headers,
  );
  return req;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After auth is completed you have to pass the access token not  the idtoken. you can get an access token like the following code.

```
  const {accessToken} = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
```